# SmtpClient - The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, smtp

I am trying to create a small app using C# to send email, but I can't get it to work even using port 587 (GMail) TLS or 465 (GMail SSL). I'm not sure what is causing my problem, should I edit my app.config file? Here is my code:

```
try
{
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
  client.EnableSsl = true;
  client.Timeout = 10000;
  client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
  client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemailid", "mypwd");

  MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
  msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
  msg.From = new MailAddress("myemailid");
  msg.Subject = txtSub.Text;
  msg.Body = txtMsg.Text;

  client.Send(msg);
  MessageBox.Show("sent");
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? Could you post the exception?

Comment: the operation has timed out

Comment: Possible causes: SmtpClient is not valid, port is not valid, username and password combination not valid, `client.Timeout` to small, no internet connection, Google is down (I don't think Google is down)

Comment: Did you check if email address and login are correct

Comment: yes i checkd not working still

Comment: Does another e-mail client work with the same settings on the same computer etc.? Could it be a firewall issue? Do you have the SSL certificate installed correctly?

Comment: Google help page: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: I've got the same error and my data is correct. Thunderbird can send from the same machine. So there must be a bug in .NET.

Answer (score 9):

Ports 25 & 465 caused problems. Changing port to 587 worked for me.

```
Dim myCredential As System.Net.NetworkCredential
myCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailid", "pwd")
smtp.Host = "server"
smtp.Port = 587
smtp.EnableSsl = True
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
smtp.Credentials = myCredential
smtp.Send(mm)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting a timeout exception, then it means that the SmtpClient was unable to either connect to the SMTP server or the connection was lost at some point during the send.

This could be caused by a firewall on your end that is blocking outgoing connections to the server or blocking outgoing connections on port 465.

Comment: I spent a day and a half debugging a similar problem only to find it was Symantec Endpoint Protection which blocked the outbound mails.  Oddly my unit tests worked, but when running as a windows service I would get this error.

Comment: I got help from a Google help page that suggested using port 25 with SSL, and that worked for me.

Comment: I am currently encountering this issue. And what annoys me is that it is intermittent

Comment: First i used port no 465 and it thrown the timeout error, finally i used 25 now its working fine for me. But i could not find why its happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, running it as Administrator sorted it for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Allow ports 25, 465, 587 on Firewall setting.
2. I could send mail by System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient or MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient

   In some mail services such as [aruba.it](https://webmail.aruba.it), System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient does not work at all.

Following is the code part using MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient

```
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit.Text;
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
...
// create email message
var email = new MimeMessage();
email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("notifiche@articolo75.it"));
//email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("yourmail@gmail.com"));// if you want to use gmail service, enable this line.
email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(destinatario));
email.Subject = oggetto;
email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = "<h1>Example HTML Message Body</h1>" };
if (password.Length > 0)
{
    msg += "Password : " + password;
}

if (link.Length > 0)
    email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = messaggio + "<a href=\"" + link + "\"" + ">Clicca qui</a>" + msg }; 
else
    email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = messaggio }; 

// send email
var smtp = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
smtp.Connect("smtps.aruba.it", 465, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect); 
smtp.Authenticate("notifiche@articolo75.it", "password");
//smtp.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);// if you want to use gmail service, enable this line.
//smtp.Authenticate("yourmail@gmail.com", "password");// if you want to use gmail service, enable this line.
smtp.Send(email);
smtp.Disconnect(true);
```

Following is the code part using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
...
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.From = new MailAddress(strFromMail);
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(strToMail));
    mail.Subject = oggetto;
    mail.Body = messaggio;

    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25/* or 587 */);
    System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strFromMail, "password");
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = basicCredential1;
    
    client.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error sending email \n"+ex.ToString());
}
```